# What is an object of a preposition

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, objects

What does it mean "**object of a preposition**"?

Could you explain it by one or two example sentences?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the object of a preposition is a noun phrase, as in _I was talking **to my friend**_; " where the object is the NP "my friend". Others use the more accurate expression "complement of a preposition", where in additional to an NP, the complement may be a predicative as in _I took him **for dead**_, an adverb phrase as in _I hadn't met her **till recently**_, a preposition phrase as in _I stayed **until after lunch**_ and even a clause, as in _I left **because I was tired**_.

Comment: Thank you for that useful comments. So simply speaking _an object of a preposition_ is the object (or noun phrase) that comes after a preposition in a sentence, right? And another question: is **because** part of prepositions please?

Comment: Yes, the noun phrase follows the preposition to complete its meaning. But as I said, it is better to talk of "complement of a preposition", since prepositions can take several other kinds of phrase/clause to complete their meaning, as in the examples I gave you. "Because" is traditionally analysed as a conjunction, but many people nowadays see it as a preposition. Another example is _It happened **after Kim left**_, where the subordinate clause "Kim left" is complement of the preposition "after".

Answer (score -2):

"Object of preposition" in [syntax](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/syntax) literally means that any [preposition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/prepositions) has an [object](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/object) *(grammar)* which directed by the preposition. (see [here](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/objectofthepreposition.htm))

Examples:

> Our university is **around** the *corner*.

In this example, the word "corener" is the object, and its preposition is the prepositional word "around". And then here is the "object of preposition". (=the object word "corner" belongs to the prepositional word "around").

Another example:

> He talked **to** *him*.

In this example, the word "him" is the object, and its preposition is the prepositional word "to". And then again we have the "object of preposition" (=the object word "him" belongs to the prepositional word "to").

---

In order to find an object in a sentence you should find the word that answer on the question “whom” or “what” is receiving the action or the desription.

For further information about it -see: [How to Find a Direct Object?](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-a-Direct-Object)

Comment: And the items other than NPs that can complement PP's?

Comment: Sorry,  I don't understand you. I wrote a simple answer for his question. Votedown for what? What's incorrect in the answer?

Comment: Please read my two messages to franky and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I did it. read here: http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/objectofthepreposition.htm

Comment: You have to account for those other items that I listed in my messages to the OP. They are not noun phrases, but they are just a much complements of prepositions.

Comment: @Industrious Don't be confused by the word "object".  When people say "the object of a preposition", they mean something very different from when they say "direct object".  The information from WikiHow does not apply here.